# Code works in Jupyter but not in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, seaborn

I know this might be a very simple problem to solve, but I have been googling all day and cannot make it work. Please be patient with me - I just started working with Python.

I have a very simple code, that I can execute well in Jupyter, but it does not work in PyCharm:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import pandas as pd
import numpy

y = pd.read_csv('data_all.csv')

df = y.iloc[:, 0:10]

print(df)

g = sns.PairGrid(df, hue='TP_PSP')
g = g.map(plt.scatter)
g = g.map_diag(plt.hist)
g = g.map_offdiag(plt.scatter)
g = g.add_legend()
```

I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lukas/PycharmProjects/untitled/mtth-matplot.py", line 18, in <module>
    g = g.map_diag(plt.hist)
  File "C:\Users\lukas\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py", line 1399, in map_diag
    func(data_k, label=label_k, color=color, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lukas\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3132, in hist
    stacked=stacked, normed=normed, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lukas\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1855, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lukas\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 6713, in hist
    labels = [six.text_type(lab) for lab in label]
TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable
```

I have all packages installed and the interpreter works for "normal" python code. I am sorry posting such a trivial problem, but I cannot find a solution on the web that works for me. I am so grateful every hint to make it work.

Thanks in advance and best regards

LGR

Comment: are you sure you are using the same interpreter to run in jupyter and in PyCharm?

Comment: I used Jupyter at https://notebooks.azure.com. Now I want to use python locally on my machine. I installed conda and set up an environment and used the conda interpreter.

Comment: you should make sure you are using the same interpreter in both cases. Could you run this in your notebook `import sys;sys.version;sys.version_info`, and can you run `python --version` from the terminal in PyCharm. Probably you are not using the same version of Python.

Comment: You might also want to check the version of the packages you're using. Most should have a `__version__` attribute in them, though it may be at the top package level and not inside any sub-modules (so you'll need to check `matplotlib.__version__`, rather than `matplotlib.pyplot.__version__`).

Answer (score 0):

This worked. I was facing a similar problem. Changed the Python Interpreter from 2.7 to 3.8 by clicking in the lower left portion of the Pycharm screen where it shows the interpreter being used. Code worked flawlessly.